# JWT token revoke for specific user on deactivate account

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

So far I have created a database with

```
user_id,token.
```

It  stores all the logged in user's token.

I have fetched all the tokens from database by user_id. Then loop through,

```
JWTAuth::invalidate(new \Tymon\JWTAuth\Token($token->token));
```

Its not working.
Third party package: Tymon Laravel JWT

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Do you use any third party package?
If yes, we should know which

Comment: Tymon laravel @WaskaChaduneli

Comment: @MdShifatulIslam why can't you reset the `token` column on deactivating that user account, because each time user will log in will have new JWT token.

Comment: @MdShifatulIslam, you can create a middleware to check if account is deactivated then add `JWTAuth::invalidate(new \Tymon\JWTAuth\Token($token->token));` to invalidate the user. By doing this if deactivated user trying to access routes, he will not get access.

Comment: @HarpalSingh Yes i did it. seems ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding here the comment of Harpal singh.It solved my issue.

"you can create a middleware to check if account is deactivated then add

```
JWTAuth::invalidate(new \Tymon\JWTAuth\Token($token->token));
```

to invalidate the user. By doing this if deactivated user trying to access routes, he will not get access."

Answer (score 0):

After long time for trace the source code. I found this works.

```
JWTAuth::manager()->invalidate(new Token({YourToken}))
```